# Recieving error based on a dll that I have removed from my project

Tags: c#, dll, reference, visual-studio-2017

I have a project running on a 64 bit server that was trying to reference a 32 bit dll. I ultimately ended up deleting this dll and all references to it. When I run the code locally (debugging) It works perfectly, but when I run it on the server, It throws the same error as it originally did in reference to the dll that no longer exists within the project. I have cleaned and rebuilt the solution. I have looked in my bin folder for any extraneous files that may have been lingering. Does anyone have any idea why I would be having this problem? I'm most confused that it is working locally but not when I push it live.

Error Details:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {60D08351-AE7E-11D4-A557-00104B6B3062} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).